# How do I create a Google API project in Intellij Idea 10.5?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, arduino

Hi and thanks for looking!

### Background

I am attempting to follow this [Android ADK (w/ Arduino) tutorial](http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-blink-an-led-with-your-phone-code-and-explanation/).

I am using Intellij Idea 10.5 as an IDE (NOT Eclipse).

I have previously set up the Android dependencies in Idea, and have no problem creating a new Android project; however, according to the [aforementioned tutorial](http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-blink-an-led-with-your-phone-code-and-explanation/), it would seem that I need to use the Google API SDK rather than the Android SDK for creating the project.

[Here is the link to the Android Open Accessory Page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html).

### Question

How do I set up Idea with the Google API so that I can create a new project of this type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create new Android SDK in IDEA, it allows to select **Google APIs** SDK if it's present. If you don't have it, run `SDK Manager` and install it. Basically, there are 2 versions of SDK for most platforms, standard and with Google APIs.

[image: Create New Android SDK]

Comment: Thanks, I did not have the SDK properly installed.